# Callback function can be changed in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, state, android-jetpack-compose

As I am doing [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects) (Step 4) from Android Developer website, I noticed it is said that the callback function can be changed even after it is passed to the Composable, and the code needs to protect it against changes. As below:

> Some side-effect APIs like [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) take a variable number of keys as a parameter that are used to restart the effect whenever one of those keys changes. Have you spotted the error? We don't want to restart the effect if onTimeout changes!

> To trigger the side-effect only once during the lifecycle of this composable, use a constant as a key, for example LaunchedEffect(true) { ... }. However, we're not protecting against changes to onTimeout now!

> If onTimeout changes while the side-effect is in progress, there's no guarantee that the last onTimeout is called when the effect finishes. To guarantee this by capturing and updating to the new value, use the [rememberUpdatedState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#rememberUpdatedState(kotlin.Any)) API:

The code:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberUpdatedState

@Composable
fun LandingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onTimeout: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        // This will always refer to the latest onTimeout function that
        // LandingScreen was recomposed with
        val currentOnTimeout by rememberUpdatedState(onTimeout)

        // Create an effect that matches the lifecycle of LandingScreen.
        // If LandingScreen recomposes or onTimeout changes, 
        // the delay shouldn't start again.
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            delay(SplashWaitTime)
            currentOnTimeout()
        }

        Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_crane_drawer), contentDescription = null)
    }
}
```

I am confused about how a callback function (onTimeout in this case) can be changed as the code doesn't make any modification on it. What I am understanding is, the onTimeout callback is saved as a State in the memory, is forgot/deleted when the Composable exits the Composition, and is re-initialized during Recomposition, which implies **change**. Therefore we have to use rememberUpdatedState to ensure the last used onTimeout (rather than an empty lambda because Composable doesn't care about execution order) is passed to the LaunchedEffect scope during Recomposition

However all above are just my assumptions since I am still new with this topic. I have read some documentation but still not fully understood. Please correct me if I am wrong or help me understand it in a more approachable way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example in Codelab provided timeout doesn't change but it's fictionalized as it might change many default Composable use
`rememberUpdatedState` which is

```
@Composable
fun <T> rememberUpdatedState(newValue: T): State<T> = remember {
    mutableStateOf(newValue)
}.apply { value = newValue }
```

As in your question and comment below it could also be used as

```
    var currentOnTimeout by remember(mutableStateOf(onTimeout))
    currentTimeout = onTimeout
```

which looks less nicer than rememberUpdatedState but both works. It's a preference or option you can choose from for same end.

`Slider` and many other Composables use `rememberUpdatedState` too

```
@Composable
fun Slider(
    value: Float,
    onValueChange: (Float) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    valueRange: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float> = 0f..1f,
    /*@IntRange(from = 0)*/
    steps: Int = 0,
    onValueChangeFinished: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    colors: SliderColors = SliderDefaults.colors()
) {
    require(steps >= 0) { "steps should be >= 0" }
    val onValueChangeState = rememberUpdatedState(onValueChange)

}
```

even if you `onValueChange` function you provide won't change most of the time, probably in few instances it might need to change, uses `rememberUpdatedState` to make sure latest value of callback is passed to `Slider`.

```
Slider(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = {
        value it
    }
)
```

In the example below Calculation2 Composable enters composition when showCalculation is true and passes a callback named operation. While calculation is going on if you change selection Calculation2 function recomposed with new operation callback. If you remember old value instead of updating it after delay ends LaunchedEffect calls outdated operation that's why you use rememberUpdatedState. So, while functions recompose callback that they receive can change and you might need to use latest one.

```
/**
 * In this example we set a lambda to be invoked after a calculation that takes time to complete
 * while calculation running if our lambda gets updated `rememberUpdatedState` makes sure
 * that latest lambda is invoked
 */
@Composable
private fun RememberUpdatedStateSample2() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    var showCalculation by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val radioOptions = listOf("Option", "Option", "Option")

    val (selectedOption: String, onOptionsSelected: (String) -> Unit) = remember {
        mutableStateOf(radioOptions[0])
    }

    Column {

        radioOptions.forEach { text ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.selectableGroup()
            ) {
                Row(
                    Modifier
                        .selectable(
                            selected = (text == selectedOption),
                            onClick = {
                                if (!showCalculation) {
                                    showCalculation = true
                                }
                                onOptionsSelected(text)
                            },
                            role = Role.RadioButton
                        )
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
                ) {
                    RadioButton(selected = (text == selectedOption), onClick = null)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    Text(text = text)
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

        if (showCalculation) {

            println(" Invoking calculation2 with option: $selectedOption")

            Calculation2 {
                showCalculation = false
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Calculation2 $it result: $selectedOption",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )
                    .show()
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * LaunchedEffect restarts when one of the key parameters changes.
 * However, in some situations you might want to capture a value in your effect that,
 * if it changes, you do not want the effect to restart.
 * In order to do this, it is required to use rememberUpdatedState to create a reference
 * to this value which can be captured and updated. This approach is helpful for effects that
 * contain long-lived operations that may be expensive or prohibitive to recreate and restart.
 */
@Composable
private fun Calculation2(operation: (String) -> Unit) {

    println(" Calculation2(): operation: $operation")
    // This returns the updated operation if we recompose with new operation
    val currentOperation by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = operation)
    // This one returns the initial operation this Composable enters composition
    val rememberedOperation = remember { operation }

    //  This LaunchedEffect block only gets called once, not called on each recomposition
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true, block = {
        delay(4000)
        currentOperation("rememberUpdatedState")
        rememberedOperation("remember")
    })

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(color = getRandomColor())
    }
}
```

You can also consider more practical situation while you load data from remote server user might interact with your app like the example above and you might need to navigate based on user's latest interaction after loading is done.

Comment: In Calculation from your first example, why don't we use `rememberSaveable` for the first variable, and for the second one, why can't we pass the `input` as a key to `remember` or use `mutableStateOf(input)` inside `remember`?

Comment: `rememberSavable` is for for retaining state across configuration changes while `remember` is for retaining across recompositions. For your second question that's what i say, you can use mutableState.value = newValue or `rememberUpdatedState`.

Comment: Removed first example to prevent confusion and added more practical scenario and source code of `rememberUpdatedState`

Comment: I got the idea of changing now - callback can be changed by passing different parameter when reusing parent Composable. But why don't `remember` and `rememberSaveable` work? The parameter `operation` is changed after each event, isn't it the new state?

Comment: because remember saves operation in Composition only. When you click any radio button you pass new callback and recomposition is triggered. Since remember doesn't have a key, it actually uses Composer as key behind the scenes, it doesn't change and stores initial operation or callback that's why you need to update it either with `rememberUpdatedState` or manually updating as in source code. Try the example with and without it to see the difference.